# How do you manually execute SQL commands in Ruby On Rails using NuoDB

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nuodb

I'm trying to manually execute SQL commands so I can access procedures in NuoDB.

I'm using Ruby on Rails and I'm using the following command:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SQL query")
```

The "SQL query" could be any SQL command.

For example, I have a table called "Feedback" and when I execute the command:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT `feedbacks`.* FROM `feedbacks`")
```

This would only return a "true" response instead of sending me all the data requested.

This is the output on the Rails Console is:

```
SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT `feedbacks`.* FROM `feedbacks`
 => true
```

I would like to use this to call stored procedures in NuoDB but upon calling the procedures, this would also return a "true" response.

Is there any way I can execute SQL commands and get the data requested instead of getting a "true" response?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The working command I'm using to execute custom SQL statements is:

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("foo")
```

with "foo" being the sql statement( i.e. "SELECT * FROM table").

This command will return a set of values as a hash and put them into the results variable.

So on my rails application_controller.rb I added this:

```
def execute_statement(sql)
  results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

  if results.present?
    return results
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

Using execute_statement will return the records found and if there is none, it will return nil.

This way I can just call it anywhere on the rails application like for example:

```
records = execute_statement("select * from table")
```

"execute_statement" can also call NuoDB procedures, functions, and also Database Views.

Comment: it's better to use exec_query if you are on PSQL because it will leak memory

Comment: I cannot find the difference between the code in your question and in your answer. They both seem to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`. Could you please point out what exactly you changed to get the data instead of just `true`?

Comment: I'm guessing the difference is that `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` is now assigned to `results`

Answer (score 190):

For me, I couldn't get this to return a hash.

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

But using the exec_query method worked.

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(sql)
```

Comment: `.exec_query` returns an `ActiveRecord::Result` object which is very handy with easily accessible `.columns` and `.rows` attributes. `.execute` returns an array of hashes which is usually more troublesome to deal with and probably heavier on memory. I had never used `exec_query`, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Just to add to the last comment, you'd typically want to use `.entries` when using `.exec_query` to get the results as an array of hashes.

Comment: This always gives me nil for the results with ActiveRecord 5 running a DELETE query?

Answer (score 46):

Reposting the answer from our forum to help others with a similar issue:

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
result = @connection.exec_query('select tablename from system.tables')
result.each do |row|
puts row
end
```

Answer (score 29):

```
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection { |con| con.exec_query( "SELECT 1;" ) }
```

The above code is an example for

1. executing arbitrary SQL on your database-connection
2. returning the connection back to the connection pool afterwards

Comment: Why will you use the connection pool instead of the connection itself? Is there any advantage? Would you have a source about it?

Comment: @bonafernando, Your database might start throwing "Too many connections" [errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html) if you have code that uses `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` without calling `ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!`. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

Comment: Yeah, before your answer I've changed and noticed I've never had any other "Too many connections" error. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Once you get the MySql::Result object

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

You can convert it to array of rows

```
results.to_a
```

will make array of this format

```
[[row1][row2]...]
```